# Display Parent Page Title and Child Page Title and Content

Tags: wordpress, parent-child, parent, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type with page attributes so I can create sub pages. I'm trying to display the title of the parent page in the h1 and then have it loop through and display the content of the child pages. The code below almost does this but it's outputting the child pages also in the first bit as h1 titles so I'm getting duplicates of the child page titles. How can I exclude the child pages and prevent them from displaying in the first part of the loop?

Many thanks.

```
<?php

echo "<ul>";
if ( have_posts() ) {
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    echo "<li><h1>".get_the_title()."</h1>";

    $args=array(
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC',
             'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                 'post_type' => get_post_type( $post->ID ),
            'posts_per_page' => 10
    );

    $childpages = new WP_Query($args);

    if($childpages->post_count > 0) { /* display the children content  */
        echo "<ul>";
        while ($childpages->have_posts()) {
             $childpages->the_post();
             echo "<li><h2>".get_the_title()."</h2></li>";
             echo "<li><h2>".the_content()."</h2></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    wp_reset_query();

    echo "</li>";
     }
    }
   echo "</ul>";
 ?>
```

**Update:** Managed to get a little bit further, almost there I think. I can now see just one sub post (the latest) and the same sub post is duplicated under each parent title either though it isn't a child of the others.

Can anyone please help me nail this last bit. Thanks.

```
    <?php $parent_pages = get_pages( array(
            'parent' => 0,
            'post_type'=> 'archive'
            ));

        foreach( $parent_pages as $parent_pages)
            { ?>

        <h1><?php echo $parent_pages->post_title; ?></h1>

        <?php
        $children = get_pages(array(
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'post_type' => get_post_type( $post->ID )
            ));

        foreach($children as $child);
        ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php } ?>
```

**Update:** Trying @robbintt suggestions, I'm now here. Not sure if I'm using the get_page_children correctly and I'm now getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_AS, expecting ';' "

```
    <?php
$parent_pages = get_pages( array(
'parent' => 0,
'post_type'=> 'archive'
) );
for ( $parent_pages as $parent_page { ?>
<h1><?php echo $parent_page->post_title; ?></h1>


<?php
$all_pages = get_pages()
$child_pages = get_page_children($parent_pages->ID, $all_pages );
for ( $child_pages as $child_page ) { ?>

    <h2><?php echo $child_page->post_title; ?></h2>
     <p><?php echo $child_page->post_content; ?></p>

<?php } ?>
```

**Update:** Here's my final working code thanks to @robbintt for the help.

```
     <?php

   $parent_pages = get_pages( array( 'parent' => 0, 'post_type'=> 'archive' ) );

   foreach ( $parent_pages as $parent_page ) {
   echo '<h1>';
   echo $parent_page->post_title;
   echo '</h1>';

   $all_pages = get_pages(array( 'post_type'=> 'archive' ) );
   $child_pages = get_page_children($parent_page->ID, $all_pages );
   foreach ( $child_pages as $child_page ) {

   echo '<h2>';
   echo $child_page->post_title;
   echo '</h2>';

   echo '<p>';
   echo $child_page->post_content;
   echo '</p>';
  }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're abusing the loop a little bit here by using the standard `while ( have_posts() ) {}`.

Instead, lets target the parent page, and then use a for loop to get the child pages.

```
/* here we include only pages with no parent */
$parent_pages = get_pages( 'parent' => 0 ) 

foreach ( $parent_pages as $parent_page ) {

  /* Proceed as you have inside the while loop, targeting $parent_page each time */

}
```

Here is the rest of the documentation so you can sort as you wish: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages#Parameters

---

Part 2:

Here's the next requested section, how to get information for child pages:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children

This function will return an array of page children.  The key here is that this loop is run inside the other loop which actually gets all the parent pages.

```
$all_pages = get_pages( array( 'post_type'=> 'archive' ) )
$child_pages = get_page_children($parent_page->ID, $all_pages );
  foreach ( $child_pages as $child_page ) {
    /* proceed with any calls on child page such as ID/title, in the format $child_page->ID */
```

Let me know how it goes! Here's the new function we are using:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children

---

Part Three:

Here I've cleaned up your code a bit for the child page section. There was a lot going on, so I standardized and simplified how you echo'd HTML and added a lot more lines. This made the design pattern a lot more visible to the human eye.

```
<?php

$parent_pages = get_pages( array( 'parent' => 0, 'post_type'=> 'archive' ) );

foreach ( $parent_pages as $parent_page ) {
  echo '<h1>';
  echo $parent_page->post_title;
  echo '</h1>';

  $all_pages = get_pages( array( 'post_type'=> 'archive' ) );
  $child_pages = get_page_children($parent_page->ID, $all_pages );
  foreach ( $child_pages as $child_page ) {

    echo '<h2>';
    echo $child_page->post_title;
    echo '</h2>';

    echo '<p>';
    echo $child_page->post_content;
    echo '</p>';
  }
}
?>
```

Here's my original writeup of this code: http://codepad.org/pLtFCI1l

Comment: This makes sense, thanks! However, I'm having trouble trying to work out where to add the code for the child pages loop and wonder if you could please help a little further. I've got this far, and can display the parent headings, just need to work out how to add the title and content from the child pages. Sorry, new to php and thanks.

`
    <?php
 $parent_pages = get_pages( array( 'parent' => 0, 'post_type'=> 'archive' ) );

 foreach( $parent_pages as $parent_pages) {
 ?>
  <h2><?php echo $parent_pages->post_title; ?></h2>
  <div class="entry"><?php echo $content; ?></div>

 <?php
 }
    ?>
`

Comment: Sure, I have updated my answer to have this segment, using the function get_page_children() from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's very much appreciated. I'm really sorry, but I'm still not getting it :-( Been playing around with this for a few hours and posted an update above. Pulling hair out and now getting a syntax error, not even sure if I've used the get_page_children function correctly.

Comment: I updated your code in this codepad: http://codepad.org/pLtFCI1l. I can see why you were frustrated. I accidentally put `for` instead of `foreach` in my previous comment, which was my error.  That's just where the fun begins though. I think you'll find my PHP edits favorable in terms of readability and syntax.  It takes a lot of practice to make code look really great, so keep working hard!  Let me know when you get the syntax right and are ready to move on.

Comment: Sorry about the slow reply, been hard at the day job, which maybe I should stick to! Many thanks for your help, I really do appreciate it.

I've updated my code to your super easy to ready syntax and the fatal error has now gone, so thanks for that!

So now I'm getting just the H1 for the parent page titles and nothing from the second part to display the child page content. I'm at a loss to see what I've missed.

Comment: Cracked it! Just needed to add an array to $all_pages = get_pages, posted my working code above. Hopefully I've written it correctly.

Really happy, thanks for all you help to guide me through this.

Comment: Great job, I'm glad it worked!! I added the array to my get_pages() so anyone else that comes won't get confused.